# Chrome contenteditable=false in contenteditable=true input Chinese issue

Tags: javascript, html, macos, google-chrome, contenteditable

I have an issue with Chrome on Macos. I put an contenteditable=false element in contenteditable=true element. Then input an emoji into the contenteditable=true element. Then input 4 characters after the emoji. Then I cannot input Chinese through pinyin.

Here is the example [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/vr26mwpy/4/). I cannot input Chinese after the last s.

It works fine on Safari, Firefox and Windows Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug of Chrome. Here are details https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151219